# Adding a time index to a pandas dataframe from google finance

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing, google-finance-api

I am using the google finance api to pull data into a pandas dataframe.  The index is a number and I would like to change it to be a date inclusive of hours and minutes.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
api_call = 'http://finance.google.com/finance/getprices?q=SPY&i=300&p=1d&f=d,o,h,l,c,' 
df = pd.read_csv(api_call, skiprows=8, header=None)
df.columns = ['Record', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']
df['Record'] = df.index

Record  Open    High    Low Close
0   0   268.19  268.48  268.18  268.46
1   1   268.14  268.23  267.98  268.19
2   2   268.11  268.19  268.06  268.13
3   3   268.05  268.16  267.96  268.11
4   4   267.93  268.1   267.9   268.06
5   5   267.98  268.01  267.89  267.92
6   6   267.95  267.99  267.86  267.97
7   7   267.88  267.95  267.85  267.94
8   8   267.78  267.9   267.78  267.88
9   9   267.94  267.96  267.68  267.78
10  10  267.91  267.95  267.87  267.94
```

Comment: So, you want to turn a number into a date. But what is the number? Is it seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like Pandas supports reading from the Google api. If you look at the raw response from the api it looks like this:

```
EXCHANGE%3DNYSEARCA
MARKET_OPEN_MINUTE=570
MARKET_CLOSE_MINUTE=960
INTERVAL=300
COLUMNS=DATE,CLOSE,HIGH,LOW,OPEN
DATA=
TIMEZONE_OFFSET=-300
a1514557800,268.51,268.55,268.48,268.55
1,268.19,268.48,268.18,268.46
2,268.14,268.23,267.98,268.19
3,268.11,268.19,268.06,268.13
```

That first datetime value (with the leading `a`) is the unix timestamp. Each subsequent "datetime" is really the data for next 300 seconds (`INTERVAL` value) from the previous row. You need to write something that will parse the header information, and use that  to create the timestamps.